# Xcode 11 - Firebase issue (No Such module "Firebase")

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods, xcode11

I have tried every possible answer on this site but none of them have worked. I have added a pod file but after I import Firebase, I keep getting the (No such module 'Firebase') error

Here is the code of my appDelegate

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  Firebase app
//
//  Created by Karan Singh on 11/21/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Karan Singh. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

and here is what my pod file looks like

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Firebase app' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
 use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Firebase app

# add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
# add pods for any other desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods

    pod 'Firebase/Auth'

end
```

I am still learning coding in Xcode - thank you for helping me out with this!

Comment: Try building the project...

Comment: Add `pod 'Firebase/Core`

Comment: `Firebase/Core` is deprecated and not necessary.

Comment: Might need to do a build to prime the Xcode module cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as Hurobaki commented,You have to add firebase/core in podfile like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FirebaseApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
    # Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'

end
```

Comment: FirebaseOSX is ancient. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk#macos-and-tvos for the current recommended OSX approach.

Comment: Firebase/Core is now deprecated. Only need to use Firebase/Analytics now, to get core functionality, since analytics is the core functionality